# SDL and g++ always produces error?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, g++, sdl

I think i have SDL installed properly but i couldn't find a way to check like `import Pygame`in python. I am using Ubuntu 13.04. This is the header in my C++ code `#include "SDL/SDL.h"`. When i run `g++ -Test -o "testcode" "lesson02.cpp"` in the code's directory i get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot open linker script file est: No such file or directory`. I am trying to follow lazy Foo's tutorial but compiling isn't really covered and I'm lost. Do i need to write something else in my compile command to include SDL? Is SDL not installed properly? Is there something wrong with my include line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add -lsdl to your g++ options.

EDIT : real solution was removing -Test option, because g++ treats this as "load script file named est".

Comment: ran g++ -Test -lsdl -o "testcode" "lesson02.cpp" and got the same error

Comment: have you installed both libsdl and libsdl-dev ? (packages name may vary according to distro, I guess you're running linux and not MinGW)

Comment: i dont know i followed the instructions for sdl if those aren't included i didn't. How would i install them.

Comment: what is your operating system ?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04, a link would be fine if the process is as simple as a terminal command

Comment: (as a side note, if you know Pygame, why not stick to it? It is only a SDL binding for Python, which is faaar more easy, and won't make a difference in performance for most simple 2D games)

Comment: So I guess you ran this cmdline ?
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev

Comment: Yeah i know that, I am not planning on spending a lot of time with sdl, but rather just use it as a way to get into C++, I figured it would be easier than starting a whole new language and module (or whatever theyre called in C++).

Comment: just ran it, no change

Comment: Oh. Then I can only strongly advice AGAINST this. SDL is a C Lib, not a C++, which will lead you into bad "patterns" for C++. Of course you can use it in C++, but if you really want to learn how C++ (and object oriented programming) works, you won't learn anything by using SDL.

Comment: OOHHHH I see.
Remove -Test : -T is option to specify script file, so it searches for an est script file.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the advice, and as long as you're giving advice, should i just use C?

Comment: It is entirely up to you :) both languages have upside and downsides, and in the end it is only about what you intend to do. In the end you will certainly end up knowing both. But I think that game making suits betters object oriented languages, because you can have a good high level logic.
In most schools you learn both C and C++, amongst some dozens other languages.

Answer (score 2):

Add `-lSDL` at the end of your compile code

Comment: @KevinKlute it's an "ell" not a 1.

Comment: I see in your original post you said you were following lazyfoo's tutorial; it does cover compiling in: "Setting up SDL"